# What is the point of casting a short as an enum, and then to a string?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am looking at and trying to understand the [DnDns](http://dndns.codeplex.com/) project, it's a very impressive project altogether, but I have come across a method, and I don't understand the reason behind it.

```
public static string GetServByPort(short port, ProtocolType proto)
{
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();

    switch (proto)
    {
        case ProtocolType.Tcp: 
        {
            TcpServices tcps;
            tcps = (TcpServices)port;
            ans.Append(tcps);
            ans.Append("(");
            ans.Append(port);
            ans.Append(")");
            break;
        }
        case ProtocolType.Udp:
        {
            UdpServices udps;
            udps = (UdpServices)port;
            ans.Append(udps);
            ans.Append("(");
            ans.Append(port);
            ans.Append(")");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            ans.Append("(");
            ans.Append(port);
            ans.Append(")");
            break;
        }
    }
    return ans.ToString();
}
```

TcpServices and UdpServices are enums. Here is TcpServices:

```
public enum TcpServices : short
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Domain Name Server Port
    /// </summary>
    Domain = 53
}
```

Here is UdpServices:

```
public enum UdpServices : short
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Domain Name Server Protocol Port
    /// </summary>
    Domain = 53
}
```

Let's say the port number is 1. The output if the protocol type is TCP or UDP is going to be:

> 1(1)

If the protocol type is anything else, the output is this:

> (1)

Therefore, I want to rewrite this method like so for my project (still giving full credit to the original developers etc):

```
private static string GetServerByPort(short port, ProtocolType protocolType)
{
    if (protocolType == ProtocolType.Tcp || protocolType == ProtocolType.Udp)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}({0})", port);
    }

    return string.Format("({0})", port);
}
```

I wrote the below short console application to test:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetServByPort(1, ProtocolType.Tcp));
            Console.WriteLine(GetServByPort(2, ProtocolType.Udp));
            Console.WriteLine(GetServByPort(3, ProtocolType.SpxII));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string GetServByPort(short port, ProtocolType proto)
        {
            switch (proto)
            {
                case ProtocolType.Tcp:
                    return string.Format("{0} ({1})", (TcpServices)port, port);
                case ProtocolType.Udp:
                    return string.Format("{0} ({1})", (UdpServices)port, port);
                default:
                    return string.Format("({0})", port);
            }
        }
    }

    public enum UdpServices : short
    {
        Domain = 53
    }

    public enum TcpServices : short
    {
        Domain = 53
    }
}
```

And this was my output:

[image: Screenshot]

However I can't help but think that the developers went to all of that complexity for a reason I am not seeing.

My question is am I right to refactor this method in the way I am planning to or is there a good reason for the way the original developers have done this that I am not seeing, and that will cause me problems down the line if I do things the simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` on an enum will use the enum value *name* if there is one. (It will give the numeric version when there's no corresponding named value.) So for example, in your `TcpServices` case, if the value is 53, the result would be `Domain (53)`
in the original code - but `53 (53)` in your suggested replacement code.

There's no point in using a `StringBuilder` here though. I'd rewrite the original method as:

```
public static string GetServByPort(short port, ProtocolType proto)
{
    switch (proto)
    {
        case ProtocolType.Tcp: 
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", (TcpServices) port, port);
        case ProtocolType.Udp:
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", (UdpServices) port, port);
        default:
            return string.Format("({0})", port);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering, I thought that initially, but I wrote a quick test application to confirm and that's not what I am seeing, hence the confusion. I have updated my question

Comment: @JMK "Calling `ToString()` on an enum will use the enum value _name_ **if there is one**." The values you call it with don't correspond to any named enum value.

Answer (score 3):

For well-known services, your output will look like this:

```
Domain (53)
HTTP (80)
HTTPS (445)
FTP (21)
```

etc. While the unknown ones will be like you've shown:

```
1 (1)
2 (2)
```

etc.

Comment: I thought so to, but I have updated the question explaining what I am seeing, and why I am confused. Am I doing something daft?

Comment: Change/append your updated code to include 53 as a port and you should see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If the value is actually one of the enum members, that function will return something like "Domain(53)" instead of "53(53)". `StringBuilder` essentially calls `ToString` for everything and for enum values that will return the name of the value, if one exists (otherwise the number).

If you want to refactor some of that code, you could move the common "(port)" part outside the switch, remove the default case altogether, and get rid of the unneeded temporary variables. I.e.:

```
public static string GetServByPort(short port, ProtocolType proto)
{
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();

    switch (proto)
    {
        case ProtocolType.Tcp: 
            ans.Append((TcpServices)port);
            break;
        case ProtocolType.Udp:
            ans.Append((UdpServices)port);
            break;
    }

    ans.Append("(").Append(port).Append(")");

    return ans.ToString();
}
```